# how to load annotations using store plugin annotatorjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, annotations

I am using Annotatorjs library and I want to display previously stored annotations using the loadFromSearch option in store plugin.

My returning JSON looks like this,

```
{"total":2,"rows":[{"id":"d41d8cd98f00b20","uri":"http://localhost/highlight/index.php","tags":[],"text"
:"","ranges":{"start":"/p[1]","startOffset":17,"end":"/p[1]","endOffset":21},"quote":"pork"},{"id":"9800998ecf8427"
,"uri":"http://localhost/highlight/index.php","tags":[],"text":"","ranges":{"start":"/p[1]","startOffset"
:31,"end":"/p[1]","endOffset":37},"quote":"salami"}]}
```

This is my js code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
//initialize annotator
var content = $('#highlightContainer').annotator();

//load tag plugin
content.annotator('addPlugin', 'Tags');
//load filter plugin
content.annotator('addPlugin', 'Filter');
/**
*load unsupoarted plugins
*This plugin provides a notification to users of these unsupported browsers letting them know that the plugin has not loaded
*/
content.annotator('addPlugin', 'Unsupported');

//load store plugin for save and retrieve annotations
content.annotator('addPlugin', 'Store', {
    // The endpoint of the store on your server.
    prefix: 'http://localhost/backend/api/web/v1/highlights',

    // Attach the uri of the current page to all annotations to allow search.
    annotationData: {
        'uri': 'http://localhost/highlight/index.php'
    },

    // This will perform a "search" action when the plugin loads. Will
    // request the last 20 annotations for the current url.
    // eg. /store/endpoint/search?limit=20&uri=http://this/document/only
    loadFromSearch: {
        'limit': 100,
        'all_fields': 1,
        'uri': 'http://localhost/highlight/index.php'
    },

    showViewPermissionsCheckbox: false,

    showEditPermissionsCheckbox: false
});
});
```

But my previously saved annotations are not getting highlight on the page load. Am I missing any attributes on the return JSON?

Comment: I am facing the same.  did you find solution for this?

Comment: Yes I did. My returning JSON structure was wrong. It should be something like this.

{
 "rows":
 [
  {
  "quote":"e thousands of a",
  "ranges":
   [{
    "endOffset":24,
    "startOffset":8,
    "end":"/div[1]/p[1]",
    "start":"/div[1]/p[1]"
   }],
  "text":"",
  "id":77
  },
  {
  "quote":"herbivore",
  "ranges":
  [{
   "endOffset":19,
   "startOffset":10,
   "end":"/div[1]/h2[1]",
   "start":"/div[1]/h2[1]"
  }],
   "text":"","id":78
  }
 ],
 "total":2
}

Comment: @deveshsinghal, check the JSON above

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to rectify this using the loadFromSearch in the store plugin. Make sure your jQuery calls the following:

```
 loadFromSearch: {
'limit': 0,
'all_fields': 1,
'uri': 'http://this/dl/'
```

}